# End of multiple streams (stream inside loop)

Tags: node.js, events, stream

Im working on a project and I have to compress several directories, and then use those compressed files to call another function. For that, I'm using
https://github.com/npm/fstream and https://github.com/npm/node-tar libraries.

```
 var fstreamR = require('fstream').Reader;
 var fstreamW = require('fstream').Writer;
 var tar = require('tar');

 for (var comp in components){ 
     // In order to build images from the Docker Api, the directory
     // containing the Dockerfile and code must be compressed
     // as tar.
     var fr = fstreamR({'path':components[comp],'type':'directory'})
     var fw = fstreamW({'path':'../../'+comp+'.tar'})
     fr
      .pipe(tar.Pack())
      .pipe(fw)
     fw.on('finish',function(){
          //do something
     })
}
```

So *comp* changes in each iteration and I create a new tar file. The problem is that I need the tar to be completed before calling the function that uses it.

I have two issues here. The first one: The callback at the event listener to the event 'finish' is never called.

The second one: If it would be working, then the callback would be launched for the value of comp corresponding to the *for* iteration in which the event listener was originally called?.

I would appreciate any suggestions to that or other ideas to work around this problem. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the first issue, try listening for `fw.on('close')` instead. Looks like the [source](https://github.com/npm/fstream/blob/32580808c20bf8a946986f27580ed5a4e440a18f/lib/writer.js#L324) may be emitting `close` and not `finish`.

Comment: Same issue listening for end :(.

Comment: Hm. You're right. `fr` will emit `end`, but `fw` does not. Try `'close'` instead -- I've updated the answer. The odd thing is, I think `finish` is the standard for [native node write streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish). Looks like the library being used breaks away from the standard, perhaps.

Comment: You were right, the event is close. And yes, `finish` is the standard, hope they change the event name.